# How to connect Django app and HTML template with proper styling?

Tags: html, django, python-3.x

Whenever I run *django* file connected with template, it shows me no styling but whenever I just run the *html* file it shows me the page with proper styling. How to solve this problem? Although the links are same in both html file and whenever I connect it with django. You can see it.

**app URL**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index')
]
```

**project url**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)


urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('app1.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html');
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/icomoon.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header role="banner" id="fh5co-header">
    <div class="fluid-container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top js-fullheight">
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse js-fullheight">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#" data-nav-section="home"><span>Home</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-nav-section="services"><span>Services</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-nav-section="explore"><span>Project</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-nav-section="pricing"><span>Pricing</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-nav-section="team"><span>Team</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
  </div>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in order to get the css files and static files in django template you have to modify your template.

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="{% static 'css/animate.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{% static 'css/icomoon.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

and place your css files and other static files in a static folder, make sure that you have these lines of code in your main url files also

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

if you have more html pages make a base.html file first and inherit the other html files from it using `{% block content %}` and `{% endblock %}`. See the doc https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/template_extending/

Comment: I put all my html css files in seperate folder by the name templates but it is not giving me styling and I put *static* in links also.

Comment: it css files should be in static folder and html files should be in templates folder, both folders are in same level

Comment: saying that NameError: name 'urlpatterns' is not defined

Comment: please post your project url

Comment: keep the static url part below the main url patterns

Comment: okay, it worked but the styling still not showing. Just text with not style

Comment: post your folder sturcture also

Comment: I am uploading the pic, check it

Comment: inside templates, keep only index.html move all the static files(css, images, sass etc) in static folder

Comment: then how should I give the links static/css/animate.css or with another pattern please tell me?

Comment: yeah, it was css/animate.css. I applied but still not showing me the styling. I applied static/animate.css/ and ../static/css/animate.css. NONE of them were working.